# How to use old dot notation for ranges in Excel formulas?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

As a veteran spreadsheet user I am accustomed to using dots for ranges.  Excel supported this in previous versions: For example, if I entered `=sum(b2.b21)` then when I hit enter Excel converted it to `=SUM(B2:B21)`.

I.e., Excel used to automatically replace my easier-to-type "dot" notation with its now-canonical "colon" notation for ranges.

However, now I'm using Excel 2016 and this no longer works.

Since I believe it should be easier for software to maintain backward-compatibility than to try to undo 25+ years of human muscle memory: **Is there a way to get Excel to continue to interpret `.` as a range delineator in typed formulas?**

(Note that I don't use any of the new `.` operations, so I don't mind disabling or breaking those for routine work.)

Comment: I have Office 365 and it still works for me.  If I enter `=sum(b2.b4)` and hit enter it changes to `=SUM(B2:B4)`  Not sure why 2016 would work different.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I just tried it on a separate Office 365 install and it does *not* work for me there either....

Comment: 3 years later... did you ever get this to work?